# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestsNotificationPermissions on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging) in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

When running my app in an IOS simulator i'm getting this error : Anyone know why ?

Btw it works fine for android.

[image]

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
```

**Code that get the permission :**

```
  getIOSPermission() {
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((settings) {
      print("Settings registered:$settings");
    });
  }


void requestIOSPermissions() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }
     if (Platform.isIOS) {
      getIOSPermission();
      requestIOSPermissions();
      connector.requestNotificationPermissions();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the FCM notification is working on Android. There are a couple of additional steps to follow when setting FCM on iOS.

1. Configuring APNs certificate.
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs
2. Uploading your APNs.
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_certificate
3. You need to enable entitlements Under Signing & Capabilities in the Xcode.[image: Make sure the Backgroud fetch and Remote notification are checked]

if you still get the error then make sure you have the following on ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m

```
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<firebase_messaging/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.h>)
#import <firebase_messaging/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.h>
#else
@import firebase_messaging;
#endif

...

@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
[FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin"]];
...
}
```

@end

Comment: I already make those step but I still get these error.

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I have added a section where the Plugin registrant that is required could be missing. Maybe you could delete the related Registrant files and let flutter create a new one for you or upgrade your flutter project to a newer version. I also encountered this issues but when I updated my project with new fresh flutter app and moved existing code to it the issue was gone.